# Jquery UI buttonset icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble adding icons to jQuery UI's buttonset's.Adding icons to buttons work fine.Does anyone have a example of this working

Thanks

Markup

```
<div id="radio" class='demo'>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Top 10 FAQ's</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">Last 30 Days</label>
</div>
```

Script

```
$("#radio").buttonset({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-ne'} });
```

Comment: what kind of trouble are you having, what have you tried and failed? show and tell

Comment: Markup

<div id="radio" class='demo'>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Top 10 FAQ's</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">Last 30 Days</label>
</div>

jQuery 

$("#radio").buttonset({icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-ne'}});

Comment: @vanzylv - You can add the markup to the question, just click edit, paste it in, highlight the code portion and click the 1's and 0's button to tab it over for proper formatting :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update:

I figured it out; it was pretty simple.

```
$("#radio1").button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-gear',
        secondary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'
    }
});
```

Thanks, all!

Comment: I'd like to add that if we create buttons dynamically (`var radio1=$(<input id='radio1' name='radio' /><label for="radio1">Text</label>)`), we need to search for the element again: `$('#radio1').button(...)` instead of `radio1.button(...)`.

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this today as well - a better way, if you're using a buttonset is to apply a class to the elements within and then use the class selector:

```
$("#choices").buttonset();
$('.graph_checks').button( "option", "icons", {primary:'ui-icon-circle-minus'})
```

Comment: @knowncitizen

Have you noticed that the secondary option does not work on a button set? $("#button-" + uniqueItemId).button( "option", "icons", {primary: 'ui-icon-closethick', secondary: 'ui-icon-closethick'})

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine via the class method that I describe above.  Not sure on the method you're using.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add icon for selected checkboxes in buttonset and update them when user changes selection.

```
var noIcon = {primary: null, secondary: null};
var withIcon = {primary: 'ui-icon-custom-tick', secondary: null};
$('#containerId input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).button("option", "icons").primary == null) {
        $(e.target).button("option", "icons", withIcon).button('refresh');
    } else {
        $(e.target).button("option", "icons", noIcon).button('refresh');
    }
});
$('#containerId input:checkbox:checked').button({icons: withIcon});
$('#containerId input:checkbox:not(:checked)').button({icons: noIcon});
$('#containerId').buttonset();
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that buttonset() re-applies the button decoration classes to the group elements, and all you need is to wrap the grouped buttons in a common element... so you can just initialize your buttons as usual, then apply buttonset() to the desired group afterwards.

This is what I do (example) :

```
var buttons = {
   '#id1': {group:'group1', options: options1},
   '#id2': {group:'group1', options: options2},
   ....
   '#idn': {group:'group1', options: optionsN}
}
$.each(buttons, function(s,o) { $(s).addClass(o.group).button(o.options); });

$('.group1').wrapAll('<span></span>').parent().buttonset();
```

Of course, all buttons that needs to be grouped together are already adjacent, but you get the point. This is just an example too!